# Java Collections - Shuffle repeats items

Tags: java, collections, artificial-intelligence, shuffle, genetic

Right, I'm doing a GA algorithm for a college project, but as I was doing the Crossover, I noticed my individual length was changed, when it should have been 100.

I am creating an ArrayList of 100 City objects (it's a version of the Travelling Salesman), and creating a path of 100 Id numbers from it and passing it into a String[]. The ids go from 0 to 99. However, when I use the Collections class to shuffle, it is shuffling them, but it's also duplicated entries. Here's the code.

```
Random r = new Random(seed);
for (int i = 0; i < popSize; i++){ // popSize is population size which is 100 normally
    Collections.shuffle(baseInd, r); //baseInd is the ArrayList of 100 City objects
    for (int ii = 0; ii < baseInd.size(); ii++){
        indPath[ii] += String.valueOf(baseInd.get(ii).getID() + "."); // This is getting the current baseInd and outputting the ID to a String.
    }
    indDist[i] = Double.toString(calculateDistance(baseInd)); //method to calculate the distance from start to end on a individual.
```

}

This is current sample output (I'll only post the first 3 as it's long winded) and I've bolded one or two repeats. There may be more but one is too many!

0: 60+74+94+39+13+76+42+60+59+27+3+19+13+44+90+33+3+84+94+66+26+15+30+65+75+37+82+86+97+60+54+10+72+22+87+59+68+82+58+33+94+13+70+58+54+31+93+25+91+10+94+14+89+73+39+67+12+41+99+46+28+62+32+96+37+46+9+81+33+36+42+**77**+1+21+39+61+41+81+23+73+42+13+66+35+51+64+2+11+96+87+75+24+50+8+86+52+32+35+73+**77**+
Distance: 13781+834427040787

1: 2+89+43+7+58+32+71+44+96+63+2+57+12+34+53+43+94+14+97+18+91+40+18+86+46+70+46+46+46+98+50+0+45+44+94+34+17+**89**+72+1+9+99+40+97+**88**+3+12+38+5+41+2+26+74+96+33+33+29+16+74+18+10+13+96+12+16+76+77+2+0+**89**+18+36+88+56+35+33+28+**88**+35+86+61+98+99+66+31+90+23+86+45+74+2+88+80+84+19+33+81+23+90+37+
Distance: 14157+066270019255

2: 69+13+20+68+8+80+58+26+57+1+45+73+83+13+32+58+10+17+76+25+99+29+28+31+68+95+88+91+19+22+86+97+75+64+1+49+19+88+55+96+3+62+23+**45**+31+63+39+52+70+70+35+2+86+49+34+49+7+2+72+37+37+81+46+23+82+7+35+65+74+64+80+43+48+3+5+46+35+30+94+55+47+**45**+79+83+58+40+95+94+98+84+28+94+61+87+1+40+83+55+18+74+
Distance: 13178+332276530997

}

I am ensuring that the baseInd contains only one occurance of 0 to 99.

```
for (int a = 0; a < baseInd.size(); a++){
    System.out.print(baseInd.get(a).getID() + "+");
}
```

It's definitely seems (maybe!) to be the shuffle that is causing it. Any ideas?

--- More Code ----

This is the method that creates the City objects. It reads from a .csv file. I'm not concerned with this as the above code prints out 0 to 99 before any shuffle.

```
public static ArrayList<City> createBaseInd(ArrayList<City> baseInd){

            BufferedReader reader;
            try {
                reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("towns.csv"));
        String line;
        String[] lines;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            lines = line.split(",");
            baseInd.add(new City(lines[0], Double.parseDouble(lines[1]), Double.parseDouble(lines[2]), Integer.parseInt(lines[3]))); //Struct is Name, X Co Ord, Y Co Ord, ID
        }
        reader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("file not found");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        return baseInd;
}
```

---

There's nothing else I can really add that relevant to the problem as the issue occurs after the baseInd is created and the output isn't edited (via mutation or crossover) at this point of the output yet.

Comment: The code you've shown doesn't correlate with the output you've given - you've shown a delimiter of `.` , not `+`. The bug could easily be in the code you *haven't* shown. I think it's much more likely that the bug is in your code than shuffle - please provide a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Additionally, is this all in a single thread, or are you using the same collection in multiple threads? That would definitely be a problem.

Comment: There are a lot more repetitions that you think, actually... second snippet, 2 is repeated 5 times. 33 is repeated 4 times. 47-49 are a noshow, etc

Comment: Sorry, I change the delimited in the output file from . to + as I was the sum of all numbers should be 4950, and I was checking a random sampling and it was easier to do that and paste into Excel with a =!

There's no threading involved at all.

Comment: Yeah, I haven't checked to see how many, as one repetition is too many.

Comment: I don't quite get what you're doing with the inner loop, but shouldn't you write `indPath[i] += ...` rather than `indPath[ii] += ...`?

Comment: The indPath is an String Array and each item in the array is a path which is 100 numbers, so the full indPath will contain 100 occurances of 100 possible routes in the problem.

The full array will contain 100 of the example outputs I gave above. What is supposed to happen is that the collections class shuffles the arraylist of city objects, the order of the ids is written to a position in the indPath and repeated until the array is full. Each path may not be unique, but each path must be made up on unique numbers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your indexing in the inner loop from

```
indPath[ii] += String.valueOf(baseInd.get(ii).getID() + ".");
```

to

```
indPath[i] += String.valueOf(baseInd.get(ii).getID() + ".");
```

Let's look at a simple example where `popSize` is `2` and the `shuffle` results in `[1, 2]` twice:

After the first iteration of the outer loop, you have

```
indPath[0] => 1.
indPath[1] => 2.
```

After the second iteration of the outer loop, you have

```
indPath[0] => 1.1.
indPath[1] => 2.2.
```

Both paths contain duplicates.

Comment: ARGH! I can't believe it was that simple! Stupid mistake! Sir, you are a gent!

Edit: As soon as you said it, I logically saw the error, but thanks for the example! One bloody thing breaks an entire project! This is why I love and hate programming equally! :)

Answer (score 0):

For the uninitiated GA == genetic algorithms.

Utilizing the shuffle for any of the standard GA operations is incorrect.  With crossover you have two parents, you find an index, and switch those parts of the index.  If what is included is your crossover method, it is just plain wrong.  It needs to look something Like this:

```
public TwoParents crossOver(ArrayList<> parentA, ArrayList<> parentB) {

  TwoParents toReturn = new TwoParents();  //This holds the new parent A and B.

  int index = r.nextInt(parentA.size());  //The crossover point

  //This is the copying part
  for(int i = 0;i<index;i++) {
    toReturn.parentA.add(parentA[i]);
    toReturn.parentB.add(parentB[i]);
  }

  //Now we crossover
  for(int i = index;i<parentA.size();i++) {
    toReturn.parentA.add(parentB[i]);
    toReturn.parentB.add(parentA[i]);
  }

  //return both parents
  return toReturn;
}
```

It is an interesting application, but if you have to visit all cities, then mutation is not an applicable operator.

Comment: I'm not using a shuffle for any of the operations (as such). I am using it to create a randomised starting population of 100 individuals of 100 cities. Once the initial population is created, the shuffle is not used again. I've not posted the code for mutation or crossover as it's not relevant at the moment! I do think it works (as in my fitness does get better over time) but the population is being generated incorrectly.

Comment: Oh and in terms of mutation, the mutation is a choice of 3 - one that swaps two random positions. One that reverses the path between two positions and one that swaps the paths between two positions.